# How to do a join with multiple conditions in the second joined table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I have 2 tables.  The first table is a list of customers.

The second table is a list of equipment that those customers own with another field with some data on that customer (customer issue).  The problem is that for each customer, there may be multiple issues.

I need to do a join on these tables but only return results of customers having two of these issues.

The trouble is, if I do a join with OR, I get results including customers with only one of these issues.

If I do AND, I don't get any results because each row only includes one condition.

How can I do this in T-SQL 2008?

Comment: Can you further clarify your question, do you mean you need to retrun a result with 2 or more issues?

Comment: @Raymund: Right, I need to return customers having BOTH issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood, I think you want something like this (if you're only interested in customers that have 2 specific issues):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Customer c
    INNER JOIN CustomerEquipment e1 ON c.CustomerId = e1.CustomerId AND e1.Issue = 'Issue 1'
    INNER JOIN CustomerEquipment e2 ON c.CustomerId = e2.CustomerId AND e2.Issue = 'Issue 2'
```

Or, to find any customers that have multiple issues regardless of type:

```
;WITH Issues AS
(
    SELECT CustomerId, COUNT(*)
    FROM CustomerEquipment
    GROUP BY CustomerId
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)

SELECT c.*
FROM Customer c
    JOIN Issues i ON c.CustomerId = i.CustomerId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers as c
LEFT JOIN equipment as e
ON c.customer_id = e.customer_id  --> what you are joining on
WHERE (
          SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM equipment as e2 
          WHERE e2.customer.id = c.customer_id
      ) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a sub query instead of Joins:

```
select * from Customer C where (select Count(*) from Issue I where I.CustomerID = C.CustomerID) < 2
```

or whatever value you want

Comment: Wouldn't that only return the rows that have 0 or 1 issues. It should be '> 1' at the end to return rows with 2 or more issues or '= 2' to return rows with only 2 issues.

Comment: as I wrote before, you can use whatever clause you want, the jist of the query is in selecting the count in the subquery, I hope you can change it to satisfy to your need.