# How to join tables with multiple keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to find a way to join the two following tables in a view where the character and the level are both combined for a key id and the stats for that character at that level are spread out. Can I do this in a view or do I need to scrap the separate tables?

Table 1:

```
Character   | Level | Attack Value|
Character A | 1     | 2
Character A | 2     | 2
Character B | 1     | 3
Character B | 2     | 4
```

Table 2:

```
Character   | Level | Defense Value|
Character A | 1     | 4
Character A | 2     | 5
Character B | 1     | 1
Character B | 2     | 2
```

Desired results:

```
Character   | Level | Defense Value | Attack Value|
Character A | 1     | 4             |2
Character A | 2     | 5             |2
Character B | 1     | 1             |3
Character B | 2     | 2             |4
```

Comment: join them using character and level

Comment: Hey there @Jeremy. This is an ok first question, however you should not use both sql-server and mysql tags, are you are almost certainly not developping on both at once. I removed the table tag, which as you would see in the tag description, should **not be used**. Please edit your question to leave either sql-server or mysql (hopefully the one you are using). Welcome to SO!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a join with multiple conditions in the second joined table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139602/how-to-do-a-join-with-multiple-conditions-in-the-second-joined-table)

Comment: you tagged two different RDMS. The answers below are similar, but obviously the syntax (ticks) are different. Remove the erroneous tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply join by multiple values

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT 
   t1.Character, 
   t1.Level, 
   t2.`attack value`, 
   t1.`defense value`
FROM 
   table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2 ON 
     t1.Character = t2.Character 
     AND t1.Level = t2.Level
```

Answer (score 2):

JOIN table 1 and table 2 using character and level

```
SELECT t1.character,
       t1.level,
       t2.[defense value],
       t1.[attack value]
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.character = t2.character
   AND t1.level = t2.level
```